# Replace breaks and spaces with "+"

Tags: jquery, replace

I have en element with a string of text where I need to replace spaces and line breaks with "+" in the second column. I have the following code:
Markup:

```
<table id="tblData">
<tr>
<td>John Smith</td>
<td>114 text text text<br/>text, text,<br/>text text<br/>text
<td>N/A</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Script:

```
$('#tblData td:nth-child(2)').each( function( index, element ){
console.log($(this).text()
     .replace(/ /g, '+')
     .replace('<br/>', '+')
);
});
```

Replacing spaces is working fine, but replacing `<br/>` is not.
What am I missing?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9cTm/2/) here.

Comment: Try to replace `/<br[^>]*>/` instead?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/nsxs2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this you need to replace \n aswell

```
console.log($(this).html()
              .replace(/(<br>| |\n|\r)/g, '+')
           );
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/T9cTm/19/)

Comment: You might use `\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r` to suit [most forms of new line characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Comment: Newlines are not converted in your demo. `.text()` does not return the new line characters. So there is no way. Your demo outputs: `114+text+text+texttext,+text,text+texttext+++++` - the expected output is `114+text+text+text+text,+text,+text+text+text+++++`

Comment: @techfoobar Can't confirm: `$("<div>my text\nhere</div>").text()` gives `"my text[NEWLINE]here"`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo - Yes, But `text()` does not auto-convert `<br>`s to `\n` in what it returns.

Comment: @techfoobar True - but that should be to simply add `<br[^>]*>` to the group. (that *would* however fail with tags called `<brick>` and other tags starting with `br`). **Edit**: `/<br(\s*\/?|\s+[^>]+)?>/i` would probably work [better](http://regex101.com/r/mJ2uC6)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace `<br/>` you have to use `$(this).html()` instead of `$(this).text()`. `.text()` will not output html tags. For the regular expression look at the other answers. A side effect of this is, that all other html tags in the text will still be there after the replacing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#tblData td:nth-child(2)').each( function( index, element ){
   console.log($(this).text()
     .replace(/ |\n|\n\r|\r\n/g, '+')// use /\s|\n|\n\r|\r\n for all spaces
  );
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9cTm/9/)